# To export data from different sql queries to separate Excel files using SSIS package

Tags: ssis, export-to-excel, ssis-2008

Here is our requirement:

1. To export data from 7 different sql queries into separate 7 Excel
   files using SSIS package 2008
2. Also add all 7 queries data to 2 more tables wherein data like excel path, filename resides in 1st table and content in 2nd table

Simple way what I can think as of now is to use Data Flow task where in I have to:

1. use OLE DB Source Task to extract data from SQL query
2. add excel destination which will generate Excel file
3. Need to search how to load excel file details and content to 2 tables explained above

Here I have to repeat this activity 7 times sequentially which is like repetitive. I am new to SSIS package, could anyone please help and suggest best way to do this? Should I use any loop container? Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Is it demanded to run them "sequentially" ? If not, better to run them parallel. 
Parallel runs will be faster than any [loop container](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/integration-services/control-flow/integration-services-containers) . Also, you need to note if all SQL queries are same but with different parameters or they're actually different?

I would suggest, you sort out these things before proceeding. But parallel approach is always the fastest way to get things done. Make sure you're not writing in same excel file if running parallel.

Comment: Hi Prabhat,
Thank you for replying. There is no compulsion to run them sequentially and will have to export data to different excel files. All I need is 7 different excel files to be generated so that I have to copy it to shared drive in another server and yes Sql queries are different from each other. 
So can you please suggest how to do in parallel? Are you suggesting to have one DataFlow inside which I can have 7 OLEDB source & Excel destination?

Also, can you tell me how will I write same query result to 2 tables as well along with exporting into excel file? Thanks in advance.

Comment: @ShruthiKrishna Yes. 1 DFT with 7 oledb and 7 destination files. you said `7 different excel files to be generated`. Research if you can dynamically create excel files. I am not sure if it is straight forward.

Comment: @ShruthiKrishna : To copy same input to multiple output destinations, use `multicast` transformation.

Comment: Sorry, it’s not same query output to 7 excel files. What I meant is, I will have to use the sql queries which I use to generate 7 different excel files. Basically, it’s like copying the query output to both excel file and to another table with additional data.

Comment: To create files dynamically, I will have to use same query right?

Comment: Try it out. Excel files needs to be present. They don't generate on-the-fly. For 1 source, you an have multiple destinations using `multi-cast`

Comment: @ShruthiKrishna : did my answer and comments work? Please upvote and mark as answer if it worked as a part of appreciation.